# Database permissions in MySQL Workbench inconsistent?

Tags: php, python, mysql, permissions

I am trying to add another user, in addition to `root` to my database.  So, I did the following in MySQL Workbench:

[image]

- clicked on the tab called "Management" shown in picture, and then clicked on "Users and Priveleges".
- Then I clicked "add account" in the lower left hand corner, and entered a user name and password, and of course it shows up in the pane on the LHS.

However, then I go into the tab called "Schemas", also shown in the piccutre above, and I click on the "i" with a circle around it, as shown in the picture below.

[image]

- Then, I click on the tab that says "Grants" and see if I'm there.  but I'm not.  How do I add my username?

I refreshed everything multiple times, so that isn't an issue.

The way I got to this problem was: I tried to access the DB using python mysql package, I get the common error:

```
_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (1044, "Access denied for user...
```

...which is why I went and added a user and tried to check the grants.

How do I change the permissions?    Thanks.

Comment: wanna do it manually i can help. i can look at workbench quick tho. i just checked it out. if you double click on Server Status a few times then the Users and Privileges seem to come alive

Comment: Once you've added your user click the _Schema Privileges_ tab and add the privileges you need. I have found it useful to open up a query window an `FLUSH PRIVILEGES` after adding accounts and changing privs.

Comment: thanks.  It was the Schema Privileges Tab that did it.